# mistakes in filter in React state

Tags: reactjs, redux, filter, include

I have got an initial state in reducer. I get from api products and I should check by key, if product was not repeated, I put it to the state. If was repeated - do nothing. Mistake is that filter does not work and products repeat.

```
    const defaultState = {  
      productsInMyList: [],
    };
   
 //get prodouct
        const { productsInMyList } = action.payload;
    
//check, if it is in state or not          
              const sameProductsInMyList =    
    !!state.productsInMyList.includes(
                productsInMyList.key
              );
         
          const newProductsInMyList = sameProductsInMyList
            ? state.productsInMyList
            : [...state.productsInMyList, productsInMyList];
    
          return {
            ...state,
            productsInMyList: newProductsInMyList,
            
          };
```

Comment: Why do you need a double `!!` to check if it is in the state or not ?

Comment: I would use only `!state.productsInMyList.includes(...)`. Can you also tell me if the productsInMyList from the API is an array of object or just a single object?

Comment: HichamELBSI, it is equating to boolean

Comment: it is a single object

Comment: Can you update question to include what `action.payload.productsInMyList` value is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect, based on a comment of yours, that `state.productsInMyList` is an array of objects and that `productsInMyList` is also an object. `Array.prototype.includes` only works with primitives and shallow object equality (i.e. reference equality).

If you are comparing objects in an array and want to know if an array contains some element matching a criteria then you will want to use [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), i.e. does there exist ***some*** element in this array meeting this condition.

```
const sameProductsInMyList = state.productsInMyList.some(
  product => product.key === productsInMyList.key
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed includes into find. Thanks all for the help.

```
const sameProductInMyList = !!state.productsInMyList.find(
        (item) => item.key === productsInMyList.key
      );
```